# How to sort PHP/MySQL query with specific rules to order by time of day?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

In my application, a user can select when particular items should be given (morning, afternoon, evening, midnight or as needed).  I need to print a summary page that displays when each item should be given.  The rules I am trying to instate for my sorting order are as follows:

1. Items should always be displayed in chronological order, with
   morning first and midnight last
2. Items that have multiple times to be
   given, should be sorted with the least number of times to give first
   (i.e. if Item #2 is to be given in the afternoon, midnight and as
   needed and Item 3 should be given afternoon, evening, midnight and
   as needed, then Item #2 should be listed first)
3. Items that are only to be given as needed should be listed last

Here is an example:

- Item #1: Morning, Evening
- Item #2: Afternoon, Midnight, As Needed
- Item #3: Afternoon, Evening, Midnight, As Needed
- Item #4: Evening
- Item #5: As Needed

I am using PHP and MySQL, and here is my query so far:

```
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT morning
                           afternoon,
                           evening
                           midnight
                           as_needed
                    FROM times                  
                    WHERE user_id = $user_id
                    ORDER BY as_needed, 
                             morning DESC, 
                             afternoon DESC, 
                             evening DESC, 
                             midnight DESC", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Any ideas on how I can implement the above rules?

Answer (score 1):

James's answer is pretty much how I would code it, but in his example, not_as_needed_times doesn't sort properly since you asked that items with least times should go first.

Edit: Ok, this behemoth will take care of [everything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5VUv.png):

```
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT
  (as_needed + morning + afternoon + evening + midnight) AS total_items,
  IF((morning + afternoon + evening + midnight) = 0, 0, 1) AS not_as_needed_times, 
  morning, afternoon, evening, midnight, as_needed
  FROM times
  WHERE user_id = $user_id
  ORDER BY not_as_needed_times DESC, morning DESC, total_items ASC, afternoon DESC, total_items ASC, evening DESC, total_items ASC, midnight DESC, total_items ASC
");
```

First we move not_as_needed_times to the end, then we push records that have morning = 1 to the top and order them by number of selected times, then we move records that have tuesday = 1 and so on.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to do the trick.  Everything is in order, except items with least times are showing with the most at the top.

Comment: Still not quite there.  Take a look at ID #9 in the example you posted.  That is "evening" only, and should come after any items that have "morning" or "afternoon".

Answer (score 0):

If morning etc. are numeric, you could do:

```
SELECT (morning + afternoon + evening + midnight + as_needed) as total_items, 
      IF((morning + afternoon + evening + midnight) = 0, 0, 1) as not_as_needed_items, 
 morning, afternoon, evening, midnight, as_needed 
FROM times 
WHERE user_id = $user_id 
ORDER BY not_as_needed_items desc, total_items asc
```

The descending sort of not_as_needed puts the as_needed only aet the bottom solving (3).  The total_items asc sorts by # total items, solving (2).  Since all the times are in one row, it's just a matter of display logic for (1).

Edit: incorporating fix for not_as_needed_items from the other poster.

Comment: All times are stored in the database as either 0 or 1, where 1 means item should be given.

Answer (score -1):

The table shouldn't have a column for each timeframe if each row will only use one timeframe. You should have just one column to identify the record's timeframe. So make your table like this.

```
times
---------------
row_id
user_id
timeframe_id
rule


timeframes
---------------
timeframe_id
name
order
```

## Query

```
SELECT * FROM times t INNER JOIN timeframes tf USING (timeframe_id) WHERE user_id = $user_id ORDER BY tf.order
```

## Secondary Query

```
SELECT * FROM times t INNER JOIN timeframes tf USING (timeframe_id) WHERE user_id = $user_id AND tf.timeframe_id = '$selected_timeframe' ORDER BY tf.order
```

You arrange the timeframes order with a sorting number in the timeframes table. Then each row will be associated to a timeframe. Once you have done that then you can change the order of the timeframes without modifying code and without changing each row in the rules table (aka times).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the table structure at this point.